# ¿Cómo modificar commits existentes sin pushear?

Tags: git, git-commit

> Pregunta original: [How to modify existing, unpushed commits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179123/how-to-modify-existing-unpushed-commits)
>    [de Laurie Young](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7473/laurie-young)

Escribí incorrectamente el mensaje de commit. En otro caso, he olvidado incluir algunos archivos al commit.

¿Cómo puedo cambiar el mensaje / archivos del commit? El commit aún no se ha enviado (sin pushear).

Answer (score 2):

> Respuesta original: [How to modify existing, unpushed commits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179123/how-to-modify-existing-unpushed-commits)

## Enmendar el mensaje de commit más reciente

```sh
git commit --amend
```

Abrirá su editor, lo que le permite cambiar el mensaje de commit del commit más reciente. Además, puede establecer el mensaje de commit directamente en la línea de comando con:

```sh
git commit --amend -m "Nuevo mensaje de commit"
```

... sin embargo, esto puede hacer que los mensajes de commits de varias líneas o pequeñas correcciones sean más engorrosos de ingresar.

Asegúrese de no tener ningún cambio en la copia de trabajo *staged* antes de hacerlo o se incluirán en el commit también. (*Los cambios no staged* no se agregan al commit).

### Cambiar el mensaje de un commit que ya has enviado a tu rama remota

Si ya has enviado tu commit a tu rama remota, entonces [deberás forzar a enviar el commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41003071/why-must-i-force-push-after-changing-a-commit-message) con:

```bash
git push <remote> <branch> --force
# O
git push <remote> <branch> -f
```

**Advertencia: el envío (push) forzado sobrescribirá la rama remota con el estado de su dispositivo local**. Si hay commits en la rama remota que no tiene en su rama local, *perderá* esos commits.

**Advertencia: tenga cuidado al modificar los commits que ya ha compartido con otras personas.** Enmendar los commits esencialmente *las reescribe* para que tengan diferentes ID [SHA](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Hash_Algorithm#SHA-1), lo que plantea un problema si otras personas tienen copias de la anterior. confirma que has reescrito. Cualquiera que tenga una copia del commit anterior deberá sincronizar su trabajo con el commit recién reescrito, lo que a veces puede ser difícil, así que asegúrese de coordinarse con los demás cuando intente reescribir el historial de commit compartido, o simplemente evite reescribir los commits compartidos en total.

---

#### Use rebase interactivo

Otra opción es usar rebase interactivo.
Esto le permite editar cualquier mensaje que quiera actualizar, incluso si no es el último mensaje.

Para hacer un squash git, sigue estos pasos:

```
// X es el número de commits del último commit que desea editar
git rebase -i HEAD~X
```

Una vez que se fusione sus commits, elija el `e/r` para editar el mensaje

[image]

#### Nota importante sobre el rebase interactivo

Cuando usas `git rebase -i HEAD ~ X`, puede haber **más** que`X` commits. Git "recogerá" todas los commits en los últimos commits de `X` y si hubo una fusión en algún punto entre ese rango, verá todas los commits así que el resultado será X + .

#### Buen consejo:

Si tienes que hacerlo para más de una rama y podrías enfrentar conflictos al modificar el contenido, configura [`git rerere`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35415925/is-it-possible-to-setup-git-merge-for-automatic-resolving-git-rerere/35417944#35417944) y deja que git resuelva esos conflictos automáticamente.

---

### Documentación

- [git-commit(1) Manual Page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-commit.html)
- [git-rebase(1) Manual Page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rebase.html)
- [git-push(1) Manual Page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-push.html)